# Restoring default values for objects

Tags: kotlin, singleton

I am using two different objects, which are used like singletons.
At some point I want the user to be able to log out and find the default values for the objects again.

Is there a better way rather than overriding the values like this?

```
objectA.variableA = ""
objectA.variableB = ""
objectA.variableC = ""
```

Comment: `class SomeClass(var x: String = "", var y: String = "", var z: String = "")` => `objectA = SomeClass();`

Comment: Take a copy of the object, and use that, leaving the original alone?  (Sounds like it's not _really_ a singleton…)

Comment: @gidds a singleton can have mutable state. It is about insuring that you only have one instance of that state for access from many locations. What makes you think the OPs state should not be a singleton?

Comment: @Laurence: The need to somehow ‘remember’ its previous values is what makes it seem unlike a singleton to me.  A singleton isn't mainly about easy access to one particular instance, as that doesn't preclude others.

Comment: @gidds I don't think the OP was interested in remembering previous values, it was about setting back to defaults. These should be constants, and always be the same, so no need to remember. Also, easy access to a single instance is pretty much the exact definition/use case of the singleton pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: @JVS are you using the `object` descriptor in these "objects" you are using as singletons? If not, and you do want a singleton, then you should look at Kotlin objects and work from there. Otherwise some more detail as to the problem you are having?

Answer (score 1):

Objects can have functions as well, so I would never try to reset an objects state to its initial state from outside that object. Rather give it a function that does it for you.

Also, you want to make sure that the reset function is in sync with how you initialise the object as well. You do not want to maintain the semantics of "default" in 2 different places, whether that is in the object or outside of it.

So, here is an example that does that:

```
object LoginSession {
    lateinit var variableA: String
    lateinit var variableB: String
    lateinit var variableC: String

    init {
        reset()
    }

    fun reset() {
        variableA = ""
        variableB = ""
        variableC = ""
    }
}
```

And now if you want to reset the state of your object you can just call `LoginSession.reset()`

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a less hardcoded way to express the same behavior. This is more or less my example from above in the shape of a function though.

Comment: @JVS So you want to not write any code but you want the variable state to be reset somehow? Can you possibly give an example of how you would do what you want to do without the use of an object, just a normal instance of a class? I think possibly your question needs more clarity?

Comment: Objects with var can provide some side-effects, because you don't know what value you will have in runtime in any part of your application. Objects in kotlin are usefull for some immutably state(for example, Constants object). Otherwise you have to implement some kind of state machine.

Comment: Also, you have a lot of unnecessary actions. If you want to have mutable var's in objects more simple was to added default values to them, and remove init function. But it's not as danger as your offer to use object without any encapsulation. You just destroy one of SOLID principle. It's wrong.
`function reset` is not clean too - what you will do, if your LoginSession will become more complicated? If it will have some fields like another objects with they own fields?

Comment: @Scrobot nowhere in the singleton pattern does it say that it is for sharing immutable state. A kotlin object is used for sharing global constants, but the OP is  saying they have mutable state in a singleton. Kotlin objects are also thread safe, so my function is as well. This implementation + the ability to reset state in 1 operation is more kotlin idiomatic than trying to revert to a java singleton pattern. If variable x has nothing to do with variable y, and would never be updated in the same operation, you would not bundle their update into a single dto. Doing so makes assumptions.

Comment: Unfortunately, `lateinit` cannot be used for primitive field types (`Int`, `Double`, etc.)

Answer (score -1):

In my point of view, it's not the best way of usage 'object'. If you want to create some Session, better to use companion object of the class. For cleaner architecture will be better create factory of Session's with (im)mutable states.

```
class LoginSession private constructor(
    val variableA: String, // here you can also define default value
    val variableB: String,
    val variableC: String
) {

    companion object {
        fun create(a: String, b: String, c: String) = LoginSession(a, b, c)    
    }

}
```

But, if you insist than you need singletones, you can modify those decision like:

```
class LoginSession private constructor(
        val variableA: String, // here you can also define default value
        val variableB: String,
        val variableC: String
) {

    companion object {
        var instance: LoginSession? = null

        fun create(a: String, b: String, c: String) = if(instance != null) instance 
            else LoginSession(a, b, c).apply {
                    instance = this
                }

        fun reCreate(a: String, b: String, c: String): LoginSession? {
            instance = null
            return create(a, b, c)
        }

    }

}
```

This solution could provide you more flexibility in your project, because you can manipulate with state of your LoginSession singleton as you need, without any consequences, like NPE or wrong values in var's. Also, as I think, this code more cleaner and scalable.

**U.P.D**

Also, I advise you to follow the recommendations of Bob Martin's and Steve McConnell, which said "If you have more then 2 arguments in functions/methods, try to join them in 1 DTO(Data-transfer Object)"

```
data class SessionDTO(val variableA: String, val variableB: String, val variableC: String)

class LoginSession private constructor(val session: SessionDTO) {

    companion object {
        var instance: LoginSession? = null

        fun create(session: SessionDTO) = if(instance != null) instance 
            else LoginSession(session).apply {
                    instance = this
                }

        fun reCreate(session: SessionDTO): LoginSession? {
            instance = null
            return create(session)
        }

    }

}
```

So, in this case you have some benefits:

- You have immutability without any side-effects. You Data have one value available from any part of your application. Try to use more immutability, as you can. If one of fields in SessionDTO will change, you have to recreate login session. And it's right way, because state of your object was changed. Read the https://www.elegantobjects.org/, it will explains a lot.
- You have flexible and scalable DTO, that you can modify in time you want.
- You have manual control of LoginSession state. You have ability to create/recreate/destroy it's instance. Kotlin's Object doesn't give this point to you.

In conclusion, i would say that Object's are not silver bullet. It's intended to create simple singletons. And thinking like an engineer, you have to choose the right way between basic implementations and more complex patterns. For example, IMHO, the best way to use Kotlin's object(I took it from the book "Kotlin in action" and modified a little):

```
object Payroll {

   /*
       it's mocked method, imagine that inside it called network request, 
       or request in database, or from local storage(json-file, xml-file) 
       or something like this.
   */
   val employees: List<Employer>
       get() = Storage.loadAllEmployees() 

   /*
       So, you can in any time call method `calculateSalary` in any part
       of your application, and calculation algorithm will 
       evaluate salary for all current employers in system. 
   */
   fun calculateSalary() {
       for(person in employees) {
           // some evaluation algorithm 
       }  
   }
}
```

Comment: You are applying a Java pattern for singleton to a Kotlin Object. Which is literally added to the language so that you do not have to deal with the complexity of doing that.

Comment: How would you update variableA by itself in this case as well? I think that all of this state is meant to be mutable, not immutable. Otherwise you would just put all of these things in constant vars.. how do you mutate this state at all actually?

Comment: @Laurence `You are applying a Java pattern for singleton to a Kotlin Object` - yes, and sometimes it's not bad decision. All points why i added in U.P.D in the answer. Your points about immutabilty - how? very simlple. Just by creating new DTO instance. More information also on U.P.D.

Comment: you are assuming that all data will be updated simultaneously. The OP has each field in an object, and seems to be updating and reading each individually. So, to update 1 you would have to submit all of the data with everything the same except the field you want to change? Also, you edited your answer to even allow this submission of data, your original solution had no way of modifying the data. Rather just say "Oh ya, good point, my data can't be changed, I have edited it to allow that"